# Why the boolean false is less than boolean true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

When I wanted to solve a sorting problem in JavaScript*, I found out the *false Boolean* is lees than *true Boolean*. Why?

I have tred the following:

```js
console.log(false < true) //return true
console.log(true < false) //return false
```

My problem:

```js
const todos = [{
  text: 'running',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'walking',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'Studying',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'learn javascript',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'learn react',
  completed: true
}]

const sortTodos = function(todo) {
  todo.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.completed < b.completed) {
      return -1
    } else if (b.completed < a.completed) {
      return 1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  })
}

sortTodos(todos)
console.log(todos)
```

Comment: Because a Boolean true is interpreted as 1, false as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `false` evaluates to `0`, and `true` evaluates to `1`. Because `1 > 0`, `true > false`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

`false` coerce to `0` on the other hand `true` coerce to `1`

```js
console.log(+true)
console.log(+false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Type coercion.

To evaluate the result of `>`, JS coerces boolean to number. True becomes 1, false becomes 0.